# Trying to make job working AWS MediaConvert (ERROR 1040)

Tags: amazon-web-services

Here is my json job.

```
{
  "Queue": "arn:aws:mediaconvert:xxxxx",
  "UserMetadata": {},
  "Role": "xxxxx:role/MediaConvert",
  "Settings": {
    "TimecodeConfig": {
      "Source": "EMBEDDED"
    },
    "OutputGroups": [
      {
        "CustomName": "123",
        "Name": "Apple HLS",
        "Outputs": [
          {
            "Preset": "System-Ott_Hls_Ts_Avc_Aac_16x9_1280x720p_30Hz_5.0Mbps",
            "OutputSettings": {
              "HlsSettings": {
                "SegmentModifier": "1"
              }
            },
            "NameModifier": "test video out"
          }
        ],
        "OutputGroupSettings": {
          "Type": "HLS_GROUP_SETTINGS",
          "HlsGroupSettings": {
            "ManifestDurationFormat": "INTEGER",
            "SegmentLength": 10,
            "TimedMetadataId3Period": 10,
            "CaptionLanguageSetting": "OMIT",
            "Destination": "s3://xxxxxx/",
            "TimedMetadataId3Frame": "PRIV",
            "CodecSpecification": "RFC_4281",
            "OutputSelection": "MANIFESTS_AND_SEGMENTS",
            "ProgramDateTimePeriod": 600,
            "MinSegmentLength": 5,
            "MinFinalSegmentLength": 1,
            "DirectoryStructure": "SINGLE_DIRECTORY",
            "ProgramDateTime": "EXCLUDE",
            "SegmentControl": "SINGLE_FILE",
            "ManifestCompression": "NONE",
            "ClientCache": "ENABLED",
            "StreamInfResolution": "INCLUDE"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "AdAvailOffset": 0,
    "Inputs": [
      {
        "VideoSelector": {
          "ColorSpace": "FOLLOW"
        },
        "FilterEnable": "AUTO",
        "PsiControl": "USE_PSI",
        "FilterStrength": 0,
        "DeblockFilter": "DISABLED",
        "DenoiseFilter": "DISABLED",
        "TimecodeSource": "EMBEDDED",
        "FileInput": "s3://xxxxx/test_video.mp4"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And it falls with :

> Invalid selector_sequence_id [0] specified for audio_description [1]

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I got this exact same error. I had to add the Audio Selectors. See the following JSON example:

```
"Inputs": [
  {
    "AudioSelectors": {
      "Audio Selector 1": {
        "Offset": 0,
        "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT",
        "SelectorType": "LANGUAGE_CODE",
        "ProgramSelection": 1,
        "LanguageCode": "ENM"
      }
    },
```

If you are using the Java SDK, add something similar to the following to your inputs:

```
AudioSelector audioSelector = new AudioSelector()
            .withOffset(0)
            .withDefaultSelection("DEFAULT")
            .withLanguageCode("ENM")
            .withSelectorType("LANGUAGE_CODE")
            .withProgramSelection(1);

audioSelectors.put("Audio Selector 1", audioSelector);
```

Comment: This answer really helps me.